# ruby pickaxe book says attr_accessor is class method

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instance, attr-accessor

In the ruby pickaxe book, there is a line that says

> attr_accessor is a class method defined in class Module

But isn't `attr_accessor` an instance method? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, all documentation I can find agrees that `attr_accessor` is an instance method of Module, and I believe it would have to be an instance rather than class method to do what it does.

My guess is that it's just a typo.  The authors were probably just trying to point out that rather than being part of the language proper, `attr_accessor` and friends are just methods of the Module class, and they accidentally said "class" rather than "instance".

**Update:** In fact, I can't find your quote in my copy (10th anniversary edition), although it's print rather than PDF, so I can't easily search it.  The closest thing I can find is:

> Class attribute declarations are not part of the Ruby syntax: they are simply methods defined in class `Module` that create accessor methods automatically.

It's quite possible that the line you quoted was edited out of editions later than yours.

**Update 2:** It's officially a typo.  Listed as page 382 in [the errata](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/errata):

> “attr_accessor is a class method defined in class Module and so is available in all module and class definitions.”
>
> It should be a private instance method--Dave Thomas

Comment: I understand what you're saying (and I was aware that attr_accessor is a method), but maybe I'm misunderstanding terminology then? According to the docs for module http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor, attr_accessor is under the "Private instance methods" section.

Comment: @JeffStorey Oh, yeah, I guess you're right.  And that actually makes sense now that I think about it.  Never mind.  I'm now assuming it's just a typo; they were probably just meaning to point out that it's implemented as part of the Module class, and accidentally said 'class' rather than 'instance'.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm going to leave this question open for a while to see if there is some other explanation, but as far as I can tell, it is just an instance method of Module

Comment: I also have the 10th edition print. It's on page 379 (in section 24.5 - Metaprogramming Class-Level macros), second sentence on the paragraph that stars with "Think back to the two examples..."

Comment: My other thought is that by class method they meant it was defined on the class and not a particular instance of the class (so they didn't mean singleton method as in the sense you can call it Module.attr_accessor, but rather you could call it on any instance of Module)

Comment: @JeffStorey Knowing the page number allowed me to check the errata -- see my update #2.